# Pip not working in blender 2.83.5

Tags: python, scripting

I am trying to install pil. I am using Windows10 blender 2.83.5 I get ImportError: cannot import name 'PackageFinder' from 'pip.*internal.index' (C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 2.83\2.83\python\lib\site-packages\pip_internal\index_*init**.py)

Comment: Can't reproduce, installs fine in 2.83.5 on Windows 10. How exactly did you try to install it?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+pip

Comment: I went to the python folder and with command python.exe -m pip install pil